# why should INVLPG be called atleast once

Tags: assembly, x86, paging, intel, tlb

I'm reading the intel system developers manual Vol3A page 4-43. Its discussing recommended invalidation to perform in order to flush the TLB. One of the recommended invalidation is:

> If software modifies a paging-structure entry that references another
>   paging structure, it may use one of the following approaches depending
>   upon the types and number of translations controlled by the modified
>   entry:
>
> — Execute INVLPG for linear addresses with each of the page numbers
>   with translations that would use the entry. However, if no page
>   numbers that would use the entry have translations (e.g., because the
>   P flags are 0 in all entries in the paging structure referenced by the
>   modified entry), ***it remains necessary to execute INVLPG at least once***

What I don't understand is the bold section. If none of the page numbers that use the entry have a translation why should we call INVLPG once? (there shouldn't be any entries in the TLB corresponding to that entry).

And even if we do call it what will its operand be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: IA32e Paging structures are walked by hardware, they are cached in an internal format. You need to tell the hardware that the previously unmapped page now may be mapped. `invlpg` doesn't really access the memory, it just need an address, even if not mapped. Think of that address as a way to specify the indices in the pages structures only.

Comment: This link from the x86 tag wiki might get you thinking about the kinds of coherency that needs to happen between page walks and page table modifications.  http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2015/08/pagewalk-coherence/.  They might just be covering their bases for speculative TLB loading, but that only makes sense if either the old or new mappings could have active TLB entries.

Answer (score 2):

> If none of the page numbers that use the entry have a translation why
>   should we call INVLPG once? (there shouldn't be any entries in the TLB
>   corresponding to that entry).

None of the new entries have a translation, but an old one where `P` was `1` might be cached. The way I read it, if not even the old ones had `P=1` then you wouldn't need to use `INVLPG`.

> And even if we do call it what will its operand be?

Pick any address that's referencing the modified structure.